# When converting a dataframe to a dictionary, how do I extract only part of the dataframe to be the key?

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime, format, key

Here is what the dataframe looks like. It was retrieved from Santiment.

```
                           ethSpent
datetime                           
2020-04-17 00:00:00+00:00       0.0
2020-04-17 01:00:00+00:00       0.0

df.todict()
```

Here is what one pair of key and value looks like

```
Timestamp('2021-04-14 20:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 0.0,
```

How do I only extract the datetime without the Timestamp and tz='UTC'?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this without changing the original `df`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date' : pd.date_range('1/1/2022', '1/5/2022', freq='1D', tz='UTC'),
    'value' : list(range(5))
})
df.assign(data=lambda x: x['date'].dt.date)[['data','value']].to_dict()

Output:
{'data': {0: datetime.date(2022, 1, 1),
  1: datetime.date(2022, 1, 2),
  2: datetime.date(2022, 1, 3),
  3: datetime.date(2022, 1, 4),
  4: datetime.date(2022, 1, 5)},
 'value': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}}
```

Like in the comments asked. You can just go with `.reset_index()` and then assigning like before:

```
df.reset_index().assign(data=lambda x: x['date'].dt.date)[['data','value']].to_dict()
```

Comment: What would this look like if the 'date' was the index instead of a column?

Comment: thank you and instead of dt.date, what could I use to get the hour in addition to the date?

Comment: use `.dt.tz_localize(None)` instead of `dt.date`

Comment: DId it work? If yes, please consider accepting my answer and close the question.